# How to make an object glow in Studio (BrickLink)

Tags: software, design, bricklink-studio, rendering

Is there a way to add glow colors to objects or parts in the [BrickLink's Studio](https://studio.bricklink.com/v2/build/studio.page)?

The thing I am trying to do is to make a glowing light bulb so I can have it as a light source in enclosed areas (Like any room) and have its impact on rendering (POV - RAY / Photorealistic Render (Eyesight)).

Is it possible? Is there any other lego designing software that supports this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I solved my problem myself.
Here's what I did:

I exported the Lego model as *Collada (.dae)*, and imported it in *Blender*. Selected the material and changed *Diffuse BSDF* (Maybe changed for you) to [*Translucent BSDF*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/translucent.html) (for cycles only), selected *Volume* as *Emission* and rendered.

Cheers

Comment: Blender hangs when I try to import the Collada file. Any idea?

Comment: @Alec This sounds like an other type of issue. I would suggest ask this question on https://www.superuser.com/